# Not able to run dacapo benchmarks on JDk13

Tags: java, dacapo

I'm trying to run daCapo benchmarks available from here (https://github.com/dacapobench/dacapobench).

I gave JAVA_HOME as `export JAVA_HOME="/home/srcshetty/Desktop/ALL_JDKs/jdk-13.0.1/"`

I have installed all the dependencies required to build the benchmark.

I tested lusearch benchmark by running `ant lusearch` inside `benchmark` folder.

It runs successfully when I use JDK12 and below and it doesn't work when I use JDK13.

I get the following error messages with JDK13.

```
[exec] compile-core:
     [exec]     [mkdir] Created dir: /home/srcshetty/Desktop/TheProjectParGC/Benchmarks/dacapobench/benchmarks/libs/lucene/build/lucene-7.1.0/build/core/classes/java
     [exec]     [javac] Compiling 824 source files to /home/srcshetty/Desktop/TheProjectParGC/Benchmarks/dacapobench/benchmarks/libs/lucene/build/lucene-7.1.0/build/core/classes/java
     [exec]     [javac] /home/srcshetty/Desktop/TheProjectParGC/Benchmarks/dacapobench/benchmarks/libs/lucene/build/lucene-7.1.0/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/codecs/blocktree/BlockTreeTermsWriter.java:97: error: heading used out of sequence: <H3>, compared to implicit preceding heading: <H1>
     [exec]     [javac]  * <h3>Term Dictionary</h3>
     [exec]     [javac]    ^
     [exec]     [javac] /home/srcshetty/Desktop/TheProjectParGC/Benchmarks/dacapobench/benchmarks/libs/lucene/build/lucene-7.1.0/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene70/package-info.java:21: error: unexpected heading used: <H1>, compared to implicit preceding heading: <H1>
     [exec]     [javac]  * <h1>Apache Lucene - Index File Formats</h1>
     [exec]     [javac]    ^
     [exec]     [javac] /home/srcshetty/Desktop/TheProjectParGC/Benchmarks/dacapobench/benchmarks/libs/lucene/build/lucene-7.1.0/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/index/PointValues.java:40: error: unexpected heading used: <H1>, compared to implicit preceding heading: <H1>
     [exec]     [javac]  * <h1>Basic Point Types</h1>
     [exec]     [javac]    ^
     [exec]     [javac] /home/srcshetty/Desktop/TheProjectParGC/Benchmarks/dacapobench/benchmarks/libs/lucene/build/lucene-7.1.0/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/index/PointValues.java:67: error: unexpected heading used: <H1>, compared to implicit preceding heading: <H1>
     [exec]     [javac]  * <h1>Geospatial Point Types</h1>
     [exec]     [javac]    ^
     [exec]     [javac] /home/srcshetty/Desktop/TheProjectParGC/Benchmarks/dacapobench/benchmarks/libs/lucene/build/lucene-7.1.0/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/index/PointValues.java:77: error: unexpected heading used: <H1>, compared to implicit preceding heading: <H1>
     [exec]     [javac]  * <h1>Advanced usage</h1>
     [exec]     [javac]    ^
     [exec]     [javac] /home/srcshetty/Desktop/TheProjectParGC/Benchmarks/dacapobench/benchmarks/libs/lucene/build/lucene-7.1.0/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/search/Sort.java:37: error: heading used out of sequence: <H3>, compared to implicit preceding heading: <H1>
     [exec]     [javac]  * <h3>Valid Types of Values</h3>
     [exec]     [javac]    ^
     [exec]     [javac] /home/srcshetty/Desktop/TheProjectParGC/Benchmarks/dacapobench/benchmarks/libs/lucene/build/lucene-7.1.0/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/util/packed/package-info.java:34: error: heading used out of sequence: <H3>, compared to implicit preceding heading: <H1>
     [exec]     [javac]  * <h3>In-memory structures</h3>
     [exec]     [javac]    ^
     [exec] 
     [exec] BUILD FAILED
```

When I run with JDK12, I had to change the source from 1.5 to 1.7 or higher and build succeeded and also I ran the benchmark successfully. But with JDK13, I get the above error, which I;m unable to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Lucene build uses the doclint feature of the compiler (`-Xdoclint`), and it looks like it became stricter in JDK 13. The flags are set in `lucene/common-build.xml`... `-Djavac.doclint.args=""`.